# cannot fetch tags from https://api.github.com webstorm

Tags: angularjs, html, webstorm, text-editor

I am unable to create HTML5 boilerplate project in webstorm.What am i missing here.Kindly suggest.[image]

Comment: It probably has to do with setting up a proxy if you are behind a corporate firewall.  I'm surprised no one has answered this yet.  I'm working on the same issue right now.

Comment: whether you were able to solve the issue if you are behind the proxy?

Comment: No, I never figured it out.  I couldn't really find a simple solution and didn't want to jump down a rabbit hole since other tasks have higher priorities.  I just setup all my projects manually or use git to clone stubs that I like.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that one has to set up the HTTP proxy if being used. The exact steps of doing the same are: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/http-proxy.html?origin=old_help

**Summary:**
Hit ctrl+alt+S. This opens up the settings window. Here hit on the drop down for Appearance and Behaviour. Then hit on the drop down for System Settings. Select HTTP Proxy and configure it. Check if it connects.

Answer (score 0):

Being located behind the corporate firewall as well, what did simply work for me was to open HTTP Proxy section under Settings and tick Auto-detect proxy settings radio button. Next time a new project is being created press Reload list (if it's not updating automatically) and WebStorm will ask for your credentials. Type them down and you are done. Give it a try!